# Plain text table to csv linux

Tags: linux, csv, text

I have some plaintext table and I need to output in csv format 
if I do the tr and replace the characters I have some problems with the field when I have 2 lines.

```
cat file.txt | tr -s '|' ' ' | tr -s '_' ' '
```

The original table:

```
 ____________________________________________________________________________
|      Name                 |   AB    | DATA     | SOME  | IF     | DATE    |
|___________________________|_________|__________|_______|________|__(UTC)__|
|   Marra Carolina Odoriz   |         |          |       |        |2019-07- |
|           Dolman           |36737202 |098787267 |  45   |   -    |09T10:35:|
|____________________________|_________|__________|_______|________|_50.289Z_|
|                            |         |          |       |        |2019-07- |
|             -              |53959997 |098543650 |  30   |   -    |09T12:02:|
|____________________________|_________|__________|_______|________|_36.746Z_|
|                            |         |          |       |        |2019-07- |
|      Vic Velazquez         |33577915 |096638025 |   -   |  6000  |09T12:40:|
|____________________________|_________|__________|_______|________|_17.754Z_|
| Gabriela Letacia Cararallo |         |          |       |        |2019-07- |
|         Vacchetzi          |43132876 |091322398 |  30   |   -    |09T12:40:|
|____________________________|_________|__________|_______|________|_40.887Z_|
```

I need the output of the csv
For this plain table example:

```
NAME;AB;DATA;SOME;IF;DATE (UTC)
Marra Carolina Odoriz Dolman;36737202;098787267;45;-;2019-07-09T10:35:50.289Z
-;53959997;098543650;30;-;2019-07-09T12:02:36.746Z
Vic Velazquez;33577915;096638025;-;6000;2019-07-09T12:40:17.754Z
Gabriela Letacia Cararallo Vacchetzi;43132876;091322398;30;-;2019-0709T12:40:40.887Z
```

If I have the original multi-line input file without the "table ascii" design, can apply this partial solution to the case? 
I had apllied:

```
while(<>)
{

    @vals = split /\ /; # split fields into the val array (now I take the blank space)
    $size = @vals;
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < $size ; $i++ )
    {
        #clean up the values: remove underscores and extra spaces
        #remove semicolons
        $vals[$i] =~ s/_/ /g;
        $vals[$i] =~ s/;/ /g;
        $vals[$i] =~ s/^ *//;
        $vals[$i] =~ s/ *$//;

        # append the value to the data record for this field
        $data[$i] .= $vals[$i];

        # special handling for first field: use spaces when joining
        $data[$i] .= " " if ($i==0);
    }
   if(/\R/)  # Taking four underscores to indicate the end of the record 
             # now taking the return of carriage of new line how end of the record
    {
        # clean up the first record; trim spaces
        $data[0] =~ s/^ *//;
        $data[0] =~ s/ *$//;
        $data[3] =~ s/\..*//;

        # join the records with semicolons
        $line = join (";", @data);

        # collapse multiple spaces
        $line =~ s/ +/ /g;

        # print this line and start over
        print "$line\n" unless ($line eq '');
        @data = ();
    }
}
```

With this solution the result it´s:

NAME;FULL;;;;;;;;;AB;;;;;;;DATA;;;SOME;;DATE;(UTC)
Marra;Carolina;Odoriz;;;;;36737202;098787267;45;-;2019-07-09T10:35:50.289Z

Dolman
;;;

Comment: That looks like a nightmare for *nix line-based text tools. Maybe a `perl` module can solve it, but you'll need a consultant. I would spend my time trying to convince the providers of the original table to give you access to their source of data, or to provide the output you need. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-line handling is tough in the shell, but is easy in, say, perl.

blocktab2csv.pl:

```perl
while(<>)
{
    chomp; # remove newline
    s/^\|//; # remove pipe at the start of the line

    @vals = split /\|/; # split fields into the val array
    $size = @vals;
    for( $i = 0 ; $i < $size ; $i++ )
    {
        #clean up the values: remove underscores and extra spaces
        $vals[$i] =~ s/_//g;
        $vals[$i] =~ s/^ *//;
        $vals[$i] =~ s/ *$//;

        # append the value to the data record for this field
        $data[$i] .= $vals[$i];

        # special handling for first field: use spaces when joining
        $data[$i] .= " " if ($i==0);
    }
    if(/____/)  # Taking four underscores to indicate the end of the record
    {
        # clean up the first record; trim spaces
        $data[0] =~ s/^ *//;
        $data[0] =~ s/ *$//;

        # join the records with semicolons
        $line = join (";", @data);

        # collapse multiple spaces
        $line =~ s/ +/ /g;

        # print this line and start over
        print "$line\n" unless ($line eq '');
        @data = ();
    }
}
```

Then

```
$ perl blocktab2csv.pl intable.txt > output.csv
```

output.csv:

```
Name;AB;DATA;SOME;IF;DATE(UTC)
Marra Carolina Odoriz Dolman;36737202;098787267;45;-;2019-07-09T10:35:50.289Z
-;53959997;098543650;30;-;2019-07-09T12:02:36.746Z
Vic Velazquez;33577915;096638025;-;6000;2019-07-09T12:40:17.754Z
Gabriela Letacia Cararallo Vacchetzi;43132876;091322398;30;-;2019-07-09T12:40:40.887Z
```

This assumes no semicolons in your fields. Easy enough to modify to handle them, though.

Comment: Scott! now with some changes to the original source of data I have the new source of data with 2 and three lines in the name fields but without the pipes and underscores, need to know to change the script to making this changes work, thank in advance! –

Answer (score 0):

Try using sed, here is a very similar example [replace pipes with commas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339599/replacing-set-of-pipe-charaters)
Your code would look more like this since you only have one pipe.

```
sed 's/|/,/g' input.csv >output.csv
```

Also I would recommend checking your file if it has any comma's in it already as this will cause you problems down the line. Possibly delimite the file with tabs for ~ if there is not a string enclosed by delimiter within the file.

Comment: Patrick thanks, but the problem with this are the same, the pipes was become a semicolon now but when I have one  row with 2 lines it´s appear one new phantom record with the second line and all other fields in blank.

Comment: Here is the look of the result:                                                                                
;  Melanie Visinia Garia   ;       52521723        ;        093454525        ;         19         ;          -          ; 2019-07-09T22:02:26.139Z ;
;          Delgado           ;                       ;                         ;                    ;                     ;                          ;

Comment: This tells me that your file is never going to be as simple as just replacing the pipes. I agree with @shelter I would reach out to whomever or where ever you are getting the file.

Comment: Scott! now with some changes to the original source of data I have the new source of data with 2 and three lines in the name fields but without the pipes and underscores, need to know to change the script to making this changes work, thank in advance!

Comment: Had maked some changes to the original solution to take a new file without the pipes and the four underscores like end of line, but cannot print the correct output wanted.. can you make some observations of my changes to sugest some to get work this modification?